# How do I make a button display "Hello World?" in an Edge Extension?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn how to make extensions for Edge.  Currently I'm trying to print "Hello, World!" to a text input box in a popup when I press a button, but it's not working.  I press the button and nothing happens.  Could you please help me?  Here is all my code for the extension.

Manifest File (manifest.json)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Extension Description",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click me!",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Popup File (popup.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Extension Popup</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
    <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript File (popup.js)

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  input.value = "Hello, world!";
});
```

Comment: What's happening with your current code, how is it not working? (Do you see any errors, does anything happen at all, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Add your script at the bottom of your body element. You are trying to give a click handler to an element that doesn't exist yet.

You should also check the browser console for errors.

**Working example:**

Click the "Button 1" button to let it say "Hello, world!".

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', function() {
  let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  input.value = "Hello, world!";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Extension Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
    <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you must have your javascript file in your head tag, use `DOMContentLoaded` to wait until the document is ready and all elements are there.

See [MDN docs: DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)